# unity greeter not showing selector

Tags: 12.10, gnome, lightdm

i have installed gnome3.7 from gnome3 ppa

and i have removed evolution using `sudo apt-get remove evolution*`

and accidentally it removed gnome, gnome-shell and bunch of other things

and now when i restart and log in it says `failed to load sessioon "gnome"`
and unity greeter is not showing desktop environment selector?
i have cinnamon, unity, installed?

i went in to recovery mode edited lightdm conf file and set session to ubuntu but still it is logging into gnome instead of unity

how i can fix this

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: It's not a bug. This behavior of gnome is intented.

Comment: I agree that it's not a bug. The user has accidentally uninstalled more than he intended, where's the bug in that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options: either remove gnome compleately or reinstall it's missing parts.

For removing gnome you will need to know what's left of it on your system (usually `apt-get autoremove` will take care of that).

Reinstalling gnome only requires that you `apt-get install gnome3`. This will reinstall everything needed to get gnome working again.

---

Note: gnome3 is a meta-package, this is so to make installation of gnome easier. This sadly also means that if you remove parts of it it will think that you want to remove all of gnome, so by using gnome you either have a ton of stuff that you'll never use or you don't use gnome at all. Sadly there's no middle path. (Actually there is, but it's major pain.)

Comment: there is no network acess in recovery mode
and apt-get autoremove does nothing

Comment: Start normally and drop to a tty? For that press Ctrl + Alt + F1 (or any other F key between 1 and 6).