# how can i mount partitons in recovery mode

Tags: 12.10, partitioning, mount, filesystem, recovery-mode

I am unable to [login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248714/unity-greeter-not-showing-selector) to my account and I want to back up my data from Documents folder
so I need to know how to mount other partitions from recovery mode.  How can I do this?

```
mv /home/username/Documents /to_my_other_partitons
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mount <what to mount> <where to mount>`. Usually this looks something like `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`. You can also specify a lot of options, which you most probably won't need. Also mounting this way requires root privileges (eg. sudo).

Answer (score 4):

There is a current [bug with Recovery Mode](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/friendly-recovery/+bug/996454). Please vote for the bug (click the green writing at the top left of that page).

The solution is to enter the following two commands as soon as you enter Recovery Mode:

```
mount --options remount,rw /
mount --all
```

This will allow you to continue normally.

Comment: i have voted for the bug

Comment: I don't think it's a bug but the design of recovery mode to keep it read-only unless explicitly made rw.